# My firebase keeps uploading The Image again and again when i try click update to change the old image in the storage with new one

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-storage

I am creating an application where the user can update his Product image if he feel like.

Although i made use of a modal so that whehn the edit button is clicked it brings a modal that shows a input block populated with the products details (name, price, ctagory, and image).

when i click upload image, it uploads the image to the databse and replaces it. But it keeps uploading the image until i refresh the browser.

Here is the code

```
let run = true;

      function UpdateAndSet() {
        if (run) {
          onValue(EcomProducts, function (snapshot) {
            SelectedProduct = snapshot.val();

            //set the Values in the Input Tags to the Array Object Varibles
            SelectedProduct[SL].Name =
              document.getElementById("product-name2").value;
            SelectedProduct[SL].discountPrice = document.getElementById(
              "product_discount_price2"
            ).value;
            SelectedProduct[SL].firstPrice = document.getElementById(
              "product_first_price2"
            ).value;
            SelectedProduct[SL].category =
              document.getElementById("product_category2").value;
            //SelectedProduct[SL].imageLink = SelectedProduct[SL].imageLink;

            let productImage =
              document.getElementById("product_image2").files[0];
            console.log("done");
            //If you upload an image- send to the databse and start uploading/ use the old image
            if (document.getElementById("product_image2").files[0] == " ") {
              SelectedProduct[SL].imageLink = SelectedProduct[SL].imageLink;
            } else {
              //upload image to storgae
              let ProductPicsLocation = refStorage(
                storage,
                "ProductsPics/" + SelectedProduct[SL].Name + new Date().toJSON()
              );

              let ProductPicUpload = uploadBytesResumable(
                ProductPicsLocation,
                productImage
              ).then(() => {
                console.log("Upload sucessful");
                //get the link
                getDownloadURL(ProductPicsLocation).then((url) => {
                  console.log(url);
                  SelectedProduct[SL].imageLink = url;
                  SetValueWithDatabse();
                  //location.reload();
                  run = false;
                });
                //Products[i].imageLInk  = donloadlinkGenrated
              });
              //Now update it to the realtime databse
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

I try using
`run = true`

then i made it false when the file was uplaoded.. But the continuious uploading didnt stop

To add to it.. Anytime i click the edit button the Update button appear. but when i click again another update button appears again and again until i refres the page..

Here is a picture of my screen
[[Project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFpsa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/928T1.png)